# Jquery tabs script

Tags: jquery, cookies, web

I want to make a website where you can toggle tabs to show or hide. I have this code.

```
var a = '0';
        b = '0';
        c = '0';
    $(function(){
        $('#googleOn').click(function(){
            var a = '1';
                set = a + b + c;
            $.cookie('settings', set);
            alert($.cookie('settings'));
        });
        $('#googleOff').click(function(){
            var a = '0';
                set = a + b + c;
            $.cookie('settings', set);
            alert($.cookie('settings'));
        })
    });
```

Anyone has an idea how to make the code more general, so that i don't have to write this piece for every tab?

cheers

Comment: You should be using commas, not semicolons, when using a single `var` keyword to declare multiple variables. As your code is right now, `b`, `c`, and `set` are globals. Also - I don't think you want to re-declare `a` inside of your click callbacks, as that will shadow the outer `a` variable. _Also_, this is just plain syntactically invalid JavaScript, you're at least missing a comma in the `$.cookie()` call. ...Also, I don't see how this code toggles tabs. Could you post a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: By defining `a = '0'` your are also declaring it as a string at first and then `a = 1` or `a = 0` as an integer within you function

Comment: i edited the code a bit, i saw it was invalid after i posted it.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of jquery tab scripts to choose from. Here is just one reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
If you are using cookies to remember what tab is selected, it may be better to use a hash value for the tab links and ad this to the URL when each tab is clicked.

Comment: i'm alreayd using the jquery UI tabs, but i want to add/remove tabs with already added content, and then save what I did, so it is the same when i return